# Defining stub methods in test_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, stubbing

Can I define all of my stub methods at one place instead of defining them in each test case?
For example i have this piece of code

```
SocialNetworks::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:update_status).returns(true)
```

in multiple test cases. But if I move it in test_helper.rb file then running test cases won't work.
Does mocha gem allowed to place these stubs at one place?

> I am using rails Minitest for testing rails app. And mocha gem for
>   stubing and mocking.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in [`setup` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/SetupAndTeardown.html), like:

```
class YourTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    SocialNetworks::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:update_status).returns(true)
  end
end
```

`setup` is called before each test case.